# How does my dual-monitor X configuration work with just one screen specified? (Nvidia)

Tags: xorg, nvidia, display, multi-monitor

I was recently figuring out how to properly configure 2 monitors with X11 and a NVIDIA card and tried many different options. Many tutorials pointed out that a 2-monitor setup should include 2 screens in the `ServerLayout` section in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, like so:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Main"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1920 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

When I tried this, no matter how I configured the `Screen`, `Devices`, or `Monitor` sections, it would result in some sort of strange display or X server error. Eventually what ended up working was using simply 1 screen in my `xorg.conf` which was generated by using `nvidia-xconfig`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Main"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Lenovo Group Limited LEN C24-10"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

What I don't understand however is *how* this works. Most dual-monitor example `xorg.conf` files I came across specified 2 screens in the server layout. The fact that my config works with just one screen and monitor specified is seemingly contradicting what I have read, unless I am grossly misunderstanding something. Could someone explain to me why this is? Would I be safe to assume that the line `Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"` has something to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually need to manually play with `xorg.conf` anymore.  Even an empty xorg.conf will often get it right (with the exception of monitor placement).  The magic is that most of this is now done behind the scenes.  The Nvidia drivers (not necessarily `nvidia-xconfig`) use xorg.conf for some hints but will do most of the configuration itself and apply appropriate default values for everything.

In the past, things used to be more difficult.  There were three main ways to do a multi-monitor setup:

- Multiple `Screen`s.  This would set up several independent desktops. You couldn't move windows from one screen to the other and if you ran a terminal, you could specify which monitor could run each application by setting `DISPLAY=`
- Twinview: This X11 extension allowed a single screen to span multiple monitors.  However X11 didn't really recognize the seam between the screens.  Therefore instead of a "primary" monitor with your status bar, your status bar would span all monitors.  If you full-screen'd an application, it would span all monitors.
- Xinerama: This X11 extension solved my problems with TwinView.  Now you could full-screen an application on only one monitor, and still move windows between the two. I'm not sure if it's an independent extension, or if it work on-top of TwinView.

The "hints" provided to the nvidia drivers via xorg are indeed related to a few of the `Option` lines:

```
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0
```

These hints define which physical monitor is which, and where they should be positioned on the desktop.  You can see that there is a little Xinerama in use here.